# Which metrics will be used in the code for below requirements

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

Which metrics can be used for below requirement using youtube api?

1. How often content was viewed after being shown in the Shorts feed
2. How many times content was shown in the Shorts feed
3. Number of videos published for the selected content and date range worldwide.
4. The change in total subscribers found by subtracting subscribers lost from subscribers gained for the selected date range and region.
5. Views per impressions shown. This measures how often viewers watched a video after seeing an impression. Wondering whether your Impressions click-through rate is high or low?
6. How many times your video thumbnails were shown to viewers. Includes only impressions on YouTube, not on external sites or apps.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics and https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports as starting material for trying to solve your problem.